# Google Script Working on Test Deploy but not working after Version deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I just want to know what to do with my script or is it script related. On test deployment my web app is working but upon real deployment, the home page is working but if I click on the button to proceed,  "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again." error appeared.

Thank you in advance for the inputs and help.

Comment: What is the URL for your published web app?
e.g. https://script.google.com/macros/s/<deploymentId>/exec? (you don't have to share the ID - but please provide the rest)

Comment: @mary here is the URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec It is the same as what you send.

Comment: I've seen this before when you're signed into multiple accounts - apps script doesn't always play nice with multi-sign in. Not sure if that's what you're seeing here. The URL looks fine.

Comment: multi-sign in for different devices or single device? Before, if I redeploy for a new version, same ID appeared. But now, different IDs are generated after deployment and the error appeared after trying if working

Comment: On a single device, and more specifically a single browser profile. I'd check to see if the web app works in fresh incognito session. If it does, click your profile picture on any authenticated Google page - see if you're logged into multiple Gmail/Workspace accounts.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, is this report useful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43

Comment: Mary, I logged out other google accounts and even restart the device. But same error still occured. Thank you. 
@Tanaike Thank you for the input. I'll check the link you provided. 
Thank you very much all for the help and inputs. Keep safe

Comment: Thank you for replying. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.